# How to create loop to get each result from the select statement query

Tags: java, sql

I'm just a newbie programmer here and I need your help on how to start working on this..

I'm trying to use/copy this existing method :

```
private String createDeleteRecord(int rowNum, String[] record) {
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(rowNum + "~D~N~");

for (int i = 0; i < (intNoOfStaticCols - 1); i++) {
sb.append(record[i].trim() + "~");
}

return sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
}
```

I'm planning to create another method which is createCancelRecord then I'll add up the query and create a loop from there. Any thoughts on how to code it? Thanks

Comment: select work_item_id 
from trnlt_act 
where npa_cd = '”+npa_cd+”' and 
nxx_cd = '”+nxx_cd+”' and 
to_char(cd_pt_isrt_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd:hh24:mi:ss') = '”+cd_pt_isrt_dt+”' and
work_item_id is not null and 
trnlt_cpl_dt is null;

Comment: I'm a little confused. You want to send an SQL query, but the code you're trying to copy has no SQL whatsoever but just builds a String. You may want to look up jdbc before committing to reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("connection url","user_name","password");//create connection

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();//create a statement 

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from table_name");  //this stores the result of select statement into ResultSet object

while(rs.next())   
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3)); ////this is the loop to print each row
```

Comment: Upon adding the code you've provided, My class got an error  "Connection cannot be resolved to a type" same as the Statement and Resultset.